# ThymeLeaf help. th:each not serializable

Tags: java, html

I'm new to ThymeLeaf and I'm having troubles understanding the error that I'm getting.  The picture shows the error I'm getting. This project was given to me as in with many more files. Although these are the files that I would consider important to the problem I'm having, but because of my low level of knowledge on the subject, I'm not exactly sure.
[image: ThymeLeaf Error]

Java, CSS, and HTML

```java
package com.newconstructs.service.api;

import com.newconstructs.domain.Animal;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


@Validated
public interface AnimalService {
  public List<Animal> findAll();
}


package com.newconstructs.domain;

public class Animal {
  public enum AnimalType {DOG, CAT, SNAKE, RABBIT}


  private AnimalType animalType;
  private String     name;
  private int        offense;
  private int        defense;
  private int        health;
  private int        items;

  public Animal(AnimalType animalType, String name, int offense, int defense, int health, int items) {

    this.animalType = animalType;
    this.name = name;
    this.offense = offense;
    this.defense = defense;
    this.health = health;
    this.items = items;
  }

  public AnimalType getAnimalType() {

    return animalType;
  }

  public void setAnimalType(AnimalType animalType) {

    this.animalType = animalType;
  }

  public String getName() {

    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {

    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getOffense() {

    return offense;
  }

  public void setOffense(int offense) {

    this.offense = offense;
  }

  public int getDefense() {

    return defense;
  }

  public void setDefense(int defense) {

    this.defense = defense;
  }

  public int getHealth() {

    return health;
  }

  public void setHealth(int health) {

    this.health = health;
  }

  public int getItems() {

    return items;
  }

  public void setItems(int items) {

    this.items = items;
  }
}

package com.newconstructs.service;

import com.newconstructs.domain.Animal;
import com.newconstructs.domain.Animal.AnimalType;
import com.newconstructs.service.api.AnimalService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.*;


@Service
public class AnimalServiceImpl implements AnimalService {
  private static final List<Animal> ANIMALS;

  static {
    ANIMALS = new ArrayList<>();

    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.DOG, "Spot", 10, 7, 17, 0));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.DOG, "Rover", 15, 5, 2, 6));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.DOG, "Fido", 8, 6, 12, 15));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.CAT, "Mittens", 18, 3, 3, 0));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.CAT, "Snowball", 5, 0, 14, 1));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.CAT, "Waffles", 8, 11, 2, 18));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.SNAKE, "Slider", 6, 16, 14, 3));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.SNAKE, "Milton", 16, 6, 11, 17));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.SNAKE, "Spike", 6, 18, 2, 5));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.SNAKE, "Alice", 9, 11, 4, 6));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.RABBIT, "Flopsy", 14, 0, 12, 2));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.RABBIT, "Peter", 18, 18, 14, 3));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.RABBIT, "Oreo", 7, 4, 9, 1));
  }

  @Override
  public List<Animal> findAll() {

    return ANIMALS;
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


#content, #header, #footer {
  width: 600px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
}

.menu > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu > a.selected {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.menu > a:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

.menu > a:focus, .menu > a:hover {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

h2.header {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}


.animal-list {
  width: 400px;
}


.animal {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 4px 5px;
}


.name {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.characteristic {
  text-align: right;
}

.type {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  float: right;
}

.rating-table, .rating-table th, .rating-table td, .stats-table, .stats-table th, .stats-table td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 4.0rem;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h2 class="header">Animal Rating</h2>
  <div class="animal-list">
    <div class="animal" th:each="animal : ${animals}">    
      <span class="name" th:text="${animal.name}">Name</span>
      <span class="type" th:text="${animal.animalType}">Animal Type</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `th:each not serializable` - It seems that the `Animal` class must be serializable.

Comment: What HTML/XML editor are you using? It looks like it's just the editor that applies strict HTML validation rules, and since a Thymeleaf template uses custom attributes, they don't validate. They don't need to, because the template is not a real HTML file. The result of sending the template through the Thymeleaf engine is. *Suggestion:* Disable validation in the editor or use another editor.

Comment: I'm using Netbeans.

Comment: BTW: I found that duplicate by simply googling `thymeleaf Netbeans`.

Comment: What should the HTML be displaying if it worked correctly? I don't think it's actually doing anything even after disabling HTML validation.